# Convert rows into columns MySQL DataBase

Tags: mysql, database-design, pivot, virtual-columns

I have two tables and I would like to generate a query relating the tables.
Until now I have this query:

```
SELECT Table1.*, table2.* FROM Table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.FK_ID = Table1.ID
```

but I return the 3 rows repeating the data in table 1.

I would like my query to return the data as follows (see image)

[image]

Any suggestions to see if it is possible to make my requirement?

Thank you!

===============================

## UPDATE

I Tried with this query

```
SELECT  Table1.*, 
    (SELECT Table2.Columna2 WHERE Table2.Columna4='ALTA') AS Name1,
    (SELECT Table2.Columna2 WHERE Table2.Columna4='ATENCION') AS Name2
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.FK_ID
GROUP BY Table1.ID
```

but in my **Name2** always is **NULL**

Comment: You can look at pivot tables that will show you how to do this, however its probably better to handle the rows in your application language.

Comment: can you provide the data as text and/or make a dbfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Table1.*, 
    (SELECT Table2.Columna2 WHERE Table2.Columna4='ALTA') AS Name1,
    (SELECT Table2.Columna2 WHERE Table2.Columna4='ATENCION') AS Name2
    (SELECT Table2.Columna2 WHERE Table2.Columna4='CLIENTE') AS Name3
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.FK_ID
```

is what you want.

But there are other ways to achieve this.